# Binary serializing an enum based property

Tags: vb.net, serialization, enums

I'm trying to clone a class via the ISerializable interface.

Unfortunately an enum based property is causing trouble:

```vb
Public Enum EngineTypeList
    BipropellantEngine
    MonopropellantEngine
    SolidpropellantEngine
End Enum


Private _EngineType As EngineTypeList
Public Property EngineType() As EngineTypeList
    Get
        Return _EngineType
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As EngineTypeList)
        _EngineType = value
    End Set
End Property
```

My method for serializing/deserializing works fine, as all my other properties get cloned without a problem, except the one above which always defaults to "0" after deserialization.

I think my that my constructor or (maybe my GetObjectDataInfo) cause(s) the error:

```vb
Public Sub New(ByVal Info As SerializationInfo, ByVal Context As StreamingContext)
    With Info
        EngineType = DirectCast(.GetValue("EngineType", GetType(EngineTypeList)), EngineTypeList)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub GetObjectDataInfo(ByVal Info As SerializationInfo, ByVal Context As StreamingContext) Implements ISerializable.GetObjectData
    With Info
        .AddValue("EngineType", EngineType)
    End With
End Sub
```

Probably the casting is total nonsense (it's the first time I'm using this...)

A secound thought: I'm not serializing the enum itself, so it's probably missing in the clone. Maybe thats the reason why enginetype defaults to "0"? But how to serialize an enum?

Comment: I'm curious why you bother with ISerializable to so everything yourself. Does the BinaryFormatter miss something on its own?

Comment: The class structure I'm trying to clone is big. Many subclasses with several hundred properties all together. I only need a few of these properties (~30) in my clone. I think it is less work to use ISerializable then to mark all properties with <nonserialized>.

Comment: For the actual question, treating the Enum as an int as in the answer should work.  Another way for cloning would be a copy constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the wrong way to go about it:

```
EngineType = DirectCast(.GetValue("EngineType", GetType(EngineTypeList)), EngineTypeList)
```

Most Enums are fundamentally an Int32.  If you have ever poked at one in Reflection, they first report `RuntimeType`, you have to look at `BaseType` to see that it is an Enum.  I dont think `GetValue` is prepared to do that.  If I try to do it that way, I get an Exception.

There are 2 other ways to get it back.  First one is to treat it as an `Int32`:

```
'GetObjectData
info.AddValue("EngineType", EngineType)

'deserializing constructor
EngineType = CType(info.GetInt32("EngineType"), EngineTypes)
```

Fetch it as `Int32` and cast it.  It also works as a string:

```
'GetObjectData
info.AddValue("EngineTypeName", EngineType.ToString)

'deserializing constructor
EngineType = CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(EngineTypes),
          info.GetString("EngineTypeName")), EngineTypes)
```

Store the `Enum` name when serializing, then get it back as string and Parse it to the Type.  Since `Enum.Parse` returns Object, you still have to cast it.

Comment: Handling the Enum as an integer works perfectly!
Thank you very much :)

Comment: I would look at a copy constructor to clone if you only want some member items copied over.  It would be simpler and more straight forward than `ISerializable`

Comment: You are probably right, but playing around with Iserializable was also a nice way to take a small look into some basic aspects of serialization, which I hadn't used before...